# WIFI USB adapter not detected RPi 3b after reboot

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, wireless, wireless-adapter

I'm using builtin WIFI adapter 802.11n Wireless LAN.

`ifup wlan0` shows:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

I tried to update, upgrade, rpi-update, it hasn't helped, but now rpi is updated to the latest firmware.

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.13-v7+ #972 SMP Sun Feb 26 20:27:50 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

`lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsmod` shows:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   12051  2 
hci_uart               19956  1 
btbcm                   7916  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             365511  22 hci_uart,bnep,btbcm
brcmfmac              222720  0 
brcmutil                9092  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              542899  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 20851  3 bluetooth,cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            24427  0 
snd_pcm                97226  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              23840  1 snd_pcm
snd                    70032  3 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
bcm2835_gpiomem         3940  0 
w1_gpio                 4818  0 
wire                   32581  1 w1_gpio
cn                      5889  1 wire
uio_pdrv_genirq         3923  0 
uio                    10204  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
fixed                   3285  0 
ipv6                  406215  22
```

Comment: Are you using a USB adapter? If builtin WIFI adapter it won't be found. Did it work **before** you ran `rpi-update`?

Comment: yes, it works for almost one month.. but after last restart it haven't connect any more

Comment: What is the output of `ip link show` ? Does it show the device wlan0 ? If not, then how is wlan0 defined in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Answer (score 0):

**Mine wouldn't work until I plugged in an external wifi dongle.**

I had my wifi info in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf prior to plugging in the dongle, and tried rebooting.

```
~ $ sudo vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

network={
  ssid="NETWORK_NAME"
  psk="PASSWORD"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

After the wifi connection was established, I could remove the dongle and my on-board would continue to work. (maybe it's a safety feature?)

Comment: my have internal wireless

Comment: Same. I plugged an external one to activate it, then the internal worked.